# Computing the galois group of $x^3+3x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I want to calculate the galois group of the polynomial $x^3+3x+1$ over $\mathbb Q$.

And I am struggling in finding the roots of the polynomial.

I only need a **tip** to start with. Not the full solution of this task.

Thanks :)

Comment: You do *not* need to know the roots to determine the Galois group of a cubic irreducible in $\mathbf Q[x]$, up to isomorphism. The group either has order $3$ and is cyclic or has order $6$ and is isomorphic to $S_3$. To decide between these choices look at the discriminant. Trying to figure this stuff out by finding formulas for the roots is the wrong way; much too tedious.

Comment: I always did tasks where I determined the roots. But in our script we also have examples where we used the discriminant. But honestly I could not figure out the connection between the discriminant and the "behavior" of the galois group. Could you explain me this?

Comment: If you must determine the roots by formulas in order to figure out the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial then you are learning Galois theory the wrong way. For instance, you could never figure out the Galois group of $x^5-4x+2$, which is $S_5$. Its roots are not expressible in terms of radicals. Doesn't your textbook discuss the computation of Galois groups of irreducible cubics using discriminants?

Comment: I see now that in the script of our lecture we discussed the galois group of polynomials of the form $x^3+ax+b$. There we used the discriminant to determine whether the galois group is $S_3$ or $A_3$. But I don't know why the discriminant can help here, also which choice I have to choose after I know the value of the discriminant.

Comment: Then read books or online notes about Galois theory to see the use of discriminants in Galois theory. A quick Google search will give you plenty of sources. Is your course not using a textbook of any kind?

Comment: Hello :) yes, we are using Bosch - Algebra (It's a german book)

Comment: Doesn't section 4.4 discuss applications of discriminants? (I do not own the book but looked at the table of contents online.) Their use in figuring out Galois groups of cubics is one of the first applications usually given, after proving the discriminant determines whether or not the Galois group acts on the roots always as even permutations or not.

Answer (score 2):

How many real roots does it have? (Use calculus.)

Comment: one real root and 2 complex roots. But I don't know how to determine them.

Comment: @Marc $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja The limit is $\infty$. I am sorry, but how does this help?:/

Comment: @Marc Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I know this already. But I see... I actually wanted to determine the roots, but it seems that this is not necessary in general? So the polynomial has 1 real zero and 2 complex zeros. One element of the galois group fixes all zeros (thats the identity) and one element is the conjugate operator, which swaps the two complex zeros. But what are the other elements?

Comment: There is a result that says if $f$(your polynomial) has $n-2$ real roots,(n the degree of $f$), then $Aut_{\mathbb Q} L \simeq S_n$.

Comment: @Marc what does it mean to "know" the roots? That's really the problem. Really all you can do is name them $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$ and figure out how Galois acts on them.

Comment: You don’t need to “know” the roots, you just have to name them. Let the real one be $r$ and the complex ones be $\rho$ and $\bar\rho$. You know that complex conjugation interchanges the last two and leaves the first one fixed. But the group $A_3$ has no elements of period (order) two. So the other choice for the Galois group, $S_3$, has to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The Galois group is a [transitive subgroup of $S_3$](http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/Groups/group-data/degree3.html) (courtesy of [Transitive Group Data](http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/Groups/)).

Combine this with the answer you get from hunter's hint.

Answer (score 0):

One of the roots is

$$\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}-\alpha^{-\frac{1}{3}}\quad \text{ where }\quad \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}.$$

In general, for $x^3 + 3px + 2q = 0$ we have the real root (there is surely at least one) given by

$$\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}-p\alpha^{-\frac{1}{3}}\quad\text{ for }\quad\alpha = \sqrt{p^3+q^2}-q.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$